# $_SESSION Variable in EE

Tags: templates, sessions, global-variables

**[EDIT - I have posted the answer to my question below]**

EE 5.2.4

I'm having issues trying to use `$_SESSION` in EE.

What I would like to do is save an Amazon cart ID in the `$_SESSION`. Working in regular PHP I'm familiar with this: `$_SESSION['cart_id'] = 1234`. However when I try to do this in EE I get errors and/or nothing happens.

I thought that *maybe* what I'm looking for is the [cache-access](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/legacy/libraries/session.html#cache-access) functionality:

So in my class I have this `ee()->session->set_cache('amz_cart', 'id', $value);`, and in my view I'm trying to see what returns from this `ee()->session->cache('amz_cart', 'id');`.

Nothing returns with this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: btw for v 5 you need to use differently - ee()->session->cache['amz_cart']['id'] = $value   &  ee()->session->cache['amz_cart']['id'] for return data.

Comment: Can I get more information about this? None of the options I'm seeing are working the same way that `$_SESSION` does. I would simply use `$_SESSION` but when I do `var_dump($_SESSION)` I get `Undefined variable: _SESSION`. I need this variable to be global. It seems like it should be a simple answer and I'm not sure why `$_SESSION` isn't permitted.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use `flashdata` to achieve your requirement. For this please follow below syntax.

**To set the Flashdata:-**

```
ee()->session->set_flashdata('your_key', 'your_value');
```

**To get the Flashdata:-**

```
echo ee()->session->flashdata('your_key');
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the response Barach! I've been trying to work with this and have run into a few problems. The docs say flashdata only works when followed by a redirect. I'm using $.ajax to run a class method and in that method I have `ee()->session->set_flashdata('amz_cart', 'test');` followed by `ee()->functions->redirect(ee()->functions->fetch_current_uri());`. This does not appear to persist, however, and I need it to be checkable across the site (if this session variable exists, show a cart in the header, for ex).

Comment: I should add that if I echo the flashdata after running the redirect in the class method `echo ee()->session->flashdata('amz_cart');` I get `{"amz_cart":"test"}`, but if I refresh the page I can't seem to retrieve the flashdata.

Comment: session->cache it is also "flash" content. It is not like $_SESSION

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though I've answered my own question by trial and error.

In my class method I can set the value like this:

```
$_SESSION['amz_cart']['id'] = $value;
```

and in the template when I want to access that value I have to do this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['amz_cart']['id'];
    session_write_close();
?>
```

I'm not sure why it works this way but it appears to be working for my needs for the time being.

I'm still interested in a more elegant or EE-based solution that will work the same way.

Thanks everybody!

Comment: it works exactly because you need to start sessions first. Two moments - better to use if ( session_id() == "" ) {
            session_start();
        }   And be careful if you do code which should work with load balancer and the user could be switch between servers because $_SESSION is not cross servers  data